# Removing NaN values from Pandas series - no prior post answers have worked

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, series

I have the following command which returns a **Pandas Series** as its output:

```
def run_ttest():
    for key,value in enumerate(data['RegionName']):
                 if value in stateslist:
                    indexing = data['differ'].iloc[key]
                    Townames.append(indexing) 
                 else:
                    indexing = data['differ'].iloc[key]
                    Notowns.append(indexing)
    Unitowns['Unitownvalues'] = Townames      
    Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'] = Notowns 
    Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'] = Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues']
    Unitowns['Unitownvalues'] = Unitowns['Unitownvalues']
    return Unitowns['Unitownvalues']
run_ttest()
```

The output prints the series `Unitowns['Unitownvalues']`:

```
0     -32000.000000
1     -16200.000000
2     -12466.666667
3     -14600.000000
4        633.333333
5     -10600.000000
6      -6466.666667
7        800.000000
8      -3066.666667
9               NaN
10      1566.666667
11     10633.333333
12      6466.666667
13      1333.333333
14    -15233.333333
15    -11833.333333
16     -3200.000000
17     -1566.666667
18     -8333.333333
19      5166.666667
20      5033.333333
21     -6166.666667
22    -16366.666667
23    -22266.666667
24   -112766.666667
25      2566.666667
26      3000.000000
27     -5666.666667
28              NaN
Name: Unitownvalues, dtype: float64
```

I have tried the following:

```
     Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'] = Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'].s[~s.isnull()]
        Unitowns['Unitownvalues'] = Unitowns['Unitownvalues'].s[~s.isnull()]
     Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'] = Notunitowns['Notunitownvalues'].dropna()
 Unitowns['Unitownvalues'] = Unitowns['Unitownvalues'].dropna()
```

But neither of these attempts have been **successful**.

There was a prior suggestion on a previous post referring to the conversion of the datatype to **'float'**, but since the type already is **'float64'**, adding **.astype(float)** does **not** solve the issue.

Would anybody be willing to give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unitowns` is a dataframe? In that case, I would do:

```
Unitowns.dropna(subset=['Unitownvalues'])
```

This wil get you a dataframe with rows dropped where `Unitownvalues` is na. If you just want the Series, `Unitowns['Unitownvalues'].dropna()` will work, but you can't assign it right back to the dataframe, as that column will not match the length of the other columns I assume you have (I guess this is the Error you are having).

Edit:
Does the following not work for you? If not, what is your error?

```
s = run_ttest()
s = s.dropna()
s
```

Comment: This seems to work: Unitowns['Unitownvalues'] = Unitowns['Unitownvalues'].replace(np.NAN,"")

Comment: It leaves me with a blank space

Comment: Indeed. Is that what you want?

Comment: Ideally, removing the row would be best?

Comment: Well, did you try what I posted?